# Changing user agent on urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.x, user-agent

How can I download a webpage with a user agent other than the default one on `urllib2.urlopen`?

---

<sub>`urllib2.urlopen` is [not available in Python 3.x](/q/2792650); the 3.x equivalent is `urllib.request.urlopen`. See [Changing User Agent in Python 3 for urrlib.request.urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226781) to set the user agent in 3.x with the standard library HTTP facilities.</sub>

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Setting the User-Agent](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/user_agent.html) from everyone's favorite [Dive Into Python](https://diveinto.org/python3/table-of-contents.html).

The short story: You can use [Request.add_header](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request.add_header) to do this.

You can also pass the headers as a dictionary when creating the Request itself, [as the docs note](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request):

> *headers* should be a dictionary, and will be treated as if `add_header()` was called with each key and value as arguments. This is often used to “spoof” the `User-Agent` header, which is used by a browser to identify itself – some HTTP servers only allow requests coming from common browsers as opposed to scripts. For example, Mozilla Firefox may identify itself as `"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"`, while `urllib2`‘s default user agent string is `"Python-urllib/2.6"` (on Python 2.6).

Answer (score 119):

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762007/3790126) a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761978/send-headers-along-in-python) a couple weeks ago.

There is example code in that question, but basically you can do something like this: (Note the capitalization of `User-Agent` as of [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), section 14.43.)

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: That method works for other headers, but not User-Agent -- at least not in my 2.6.2 installation.  User-Agent is ignored for some reason.

Comment: I believe `User-agent` should in-fact be `User-Agent` (The A is capitalised) Seems to work for me when done so.

Comment: Header names are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 105):

```
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
req = urllib2.Request('www.example.com', None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Or, a bit shorter:

```
req = urllib2.Request('www.example.com', headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: With named parameters you can do this in two lines. Remove the first line and replace the second with this: `req = urllib2.Request('www.example.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})`. I prefer this form for making just a single request.

Comment: Or even shorter, in one line: `html = urlopen(Request('http://www.example.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})).read()`

Answer (score 15):

For python 3, urllib is split into 3 modules...

```
import urllib.request
req = urllib.request.Request(url="http://localhost/", headers={'User-Agent':' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0'})
handler = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: This helped wonderfully. I don't understand why i need request.Request and then repeat urllib.request.urlopen where the old version would just do urllib.urlopen(req) fine but either way, this works and I know how to use it in python 3 now.

Comment: I am still getting Error 404 :(

Comment: I've removed the confusing `data=b'None'` parameter from the answer. It transformed the example request to POST with invalid data. Probably the reason of the failure in your case, @Maksim

Answer (score 9):

All these should work in theory, but (with Python 2.7.2 on Windows at least) any time you send a custom User-agent header, urllib2 doesn't send that header.  If you don't try to send a User-agent header, it sends the default Python / urllib2

None of these methods seem to work for adding User-agent but they work for other headers:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
opener.addheaders = {'User-agent':'Custom user agent'}
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-agent':'Custom user agent'})

request.headers['User-agent'] = 'Custom user agent'

request.add_header('User-agent', 'Custom user agent')
```

Comment: `opener.addheaders` should probably be `[('User-agent', 'Custom user agent')]`. Otherwise all these methods should work (I've tested on Python 2.7.3 (Linux)). In your case it might break because you use the proxy argument wrong.

Comment: For me the build_opener call returns with a default User-Agent being already defined in the headers. So appending will just create another User-Agent header, which as 2nd will be ignored. That's why @jcoon's sol is working.

Answer (score 6):

For `urllib` you can use:

```
from urllib import FancyURLopener

class MyOpener(FancyURLopener, object):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'

myopener = MyOpener()
myopener.retrieve('https://www.google.com/search?q=test', 'useragent.html')
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution in `urllib2` and Python 2.7:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/')
req.add_unredirected_header('User-Agent', 'Custom User-Agent')
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: I get an error 404 for a page that exist if url entered trough my browser

Answer (score 2):

there are two properties of `urllib.URLopener()` namely:
`addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Python-urllib/1.17'), ('Accept', '*/*')]` and
`version = 'Python-urllib/1.17'`.
To fool the website you need to changes both of these values to an accepted User-Agent. for e.g.
Chrome browser : `'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.149 Safari/537.36'`
Google bot : `'Googlebot/2.1'`
like this

```
import urllib
page_extractor=urllib.URLopener()  
page_extractor.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Googlebot/2.1'), ('Accept', '*/*')]  
page_extractor.version = 'Googlebot/2.1'
page_extractor.retrieve(<url>, <file_path>)
```

changing just one property does not work because the website marks it as a suspicious request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
html_source_code = requests.get("http://www.example.com/",
                   headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36',
                            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                            'x-runtime': '148ms'}, 
                   allow_redirects=True).content
```

Comment: The question explicitly discusses `urllib2` and not other modules.