# Python's urllib2 doesn't work on some sites

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I found that you can't read from some sites using Python's urllib2(or urllib). An example...

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://www.dafont.com/").read()
# Returns ''
```

These sites work when you visit the site with a browser. I can even scrape them using PHP(didn't try other languages). I have seen other sites with the same issue - but can't remember the URL at the moment.

My questions are...

1. What is the cause of this issue?
2. Any workarounds?

Comment: This shouldn't be flagged a wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it gets blocked by the User-Agent. You can change User-Agent using the following sample code:

```
USERAGENT = 'something'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': USERAGENT}

req = urllib2.Request(URL_HERE, headers=HEADERS)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
s = f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: These cluelessly-run sites seem intent on forcing everyone to use a generic UA, ultimately breaking the header for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting a different user agent. Check the answers in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen).

Answer (score 0):

I'm the guy who posted the question. I have some suspicions - but not sure about them - that's why I posted the question here.

### What is the cause of this issue?

I think its due to the host blocking the urllib library using robot.txt or htaccess. But not sure about it. Not even sure if its possible.

### Any workaround for this issue?

If you are in Unix, this will work...

```
contents = commands.getoutput("curl -s '"+url+"'")
```

Comment: use an outdated module to shell out to a platform specific external program?  /facepalm