# Why is python's urllib2.urlopen giving me a 403 error?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, http-status-code-403, python-2.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python’s urllib2 doesn’t work on some sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572266/pythons-urllib2-doesnt-work-on-some-sites)

Ok, I just want to access this URL using python: http://www.gocomics.com/wizardofid/2013/01/22

But, whenever I call urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gocomics.com/wizardofid/2013/01/22').read(), it gives me a 403 error. With urllib, all I can do is read the error page, but urllib2 raises the error. When I look at the page in Chrome, it doesn't give me any problems. Why is this, and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. I tried using a user agent, it didn't work.

Comment: @SimpleCoder basically, all i did was urllib2.urlopen('http://www.gocomics.com/wizardofid/2013/01/22').read()

Comment: @SimpleCoder and urllib.urlopen('http://www.gocomics.com/wizardofid/2013/01/22').read()

Answer (score 3):

This particular website requires a "browser-like" `User-Agent` header, otherwise it will deny access.

Try adding a header, like (for instance) this:

```
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
print urllib2.urlopen('http://gocomics.com/wizardofid/2013/01/22').read()
```