# Get browser object via python?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm ready to write a program to analyze some statics in webpages,
and I found many python library for HTML DOM parsing such as [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/), [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)...
However, I found it hard to access browser object like `window` object by python.
Is it possible to use python to fetch browser object just like javascript?
e.g `window.location`
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: When parsing HTML from Python, there's no browser window you could possibly access.  I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Sven Marnach Can python set user agent option like `curl --user-agent`?

Comment: @YeJabin: That's a completely separate question, and can be answered with a Google or SO eacrh in just a few seconds:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. The window object is available only for JavaScript code running inside a browser, but you are parsing a HTML file in a Python script. Maybe you should ask a more specific question explaining in more detail what are you actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try PyQt's QWebkit, it can access and evaluate JavaScript.