# Pulling URLs in python vs UNIX

Tags: python, web-services, parsing, unix, curl

I am trying to pull a specific URL using the the python by using raw_html = urlopen(url).read().

When I inspect 'raw_htm' I find that the expected HTML/text has been replaced with some text that essentially tells me that I cannot crawl the site.

However, when I pull the same url using 'curl -O' from UNIX/python the page is downloaded just fine.

What is the reason for the discrepancy and what method should I use within python so that I can get the html as I do with the curl command in unix?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

Comment: Have you considered honoring the site owner's wishes and not crawling their site?

Comment: I would suggest reading the `robots.txt` of the website and honoring it. If it says don't crawl, then don't crawl

Comment: I am learning python and was learning how to download and parse a web page - just thought the discrepancy was curious so thought I would ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an HTTP client makes a request, it identifies itself to the server. In this case, the server checks whether the client is a bot, and if it is, it refuses access (though apparently it fails to detect Curl).

You can get around this by setting the user-agent string to spoof a browser. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen) for how to do that with `urllib`. However, if the server's owner does not want you to crawl it, and it detects that you're doing so anyway (because you're requesting pages at too high a rate), you might find yourself blocked from accessing the site, so contacting the owner might be a better idea than spoofing.

Comment: Thanks for this - though still wondering how curl was able to do it, which is what I was thinking was interesting.