# Python PIL: IOError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get the image from the following URL:

```
image_url = http://www.eatwell101.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Potato-Pancakes-recipe.jpg?b14316
```

When I navigate to it in a browser, it sure looks like an image. But I get an error when I try:

```
import urllib, cStringIO, PIL
from PIL import Image

img_file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen(image_url).read())   
image = Image.open(img_file)
```

> IOError: cannot identify image file

I have copied hundreds of images this way, so I'm not sure what's special here. Can I get this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem exists not in the image.

```
>>> urllib.urlopen(image_url).read()
'\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"\n "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>403 You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <h1>Error 403 You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.</h1>\n    <p>You are banned from this site.  Please contact via a different client configuration if you believe that this is a mistake.</p>\n    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>\n    <p>XID: 1806024796</p>\n    <hr>\n    <p>Varnish cache server</p>\n  </body>\n</html>\n'
```

Using [user agent header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802246/2491879) will solve the problem.

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(image_url)
img_file = cStringIO.StringIO(response.read())   
image = Image.open(img_file)
```

Comment: This heder was also required for some other images: ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')

Answer (score 4):

when I open the file using

```
In [3]: f = urllib.urlopen('http://www.eatwell101.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Potato-Pancakes-recipe.jpg')

In [9]: f.code
Out[9]: 403
```

This is not returning an image.

You could try specifing a user-agent header to see if you can trick the server into thinking you are a browser.

Using `requests` library (because it is easier to send header information)

```
In [7]: f = requests.get('http://www.eatwell101.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Potato-Pancakes-recipe.jpg', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0,gzip(gfe)'})
In [8]: f.status_code
Out[8]: 200
```

Answer (score 2):

To get some image , you can first save the image and then , load it to PIL . for example:

```
import urllib2,PIL

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(), urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
image_content = opener.open("http://www.eatwell101.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Potato-Pancakes-recipe.jpg?b14316").read()
opener.close()

save_dir = r"/some/folder/to/save/image.jpg"
f = open(save_dir,'wb')
f.write(image_content)
f.close()

image = Image.open(save_dir)
...
```