# Python: User-agent information urllib retrieve()

Tags: user-agent, urllib

I am attempting to use the following code to save a image from URL using python:

> ```
> image = urllib.URLopener()
> image.retrieve("http://example.com/image.jpg","image.jpg")
> ```

The image saves as expected, I was wondering whether it would be possible to set assign a User-agent using the urllib method?

Answer (score 2):

i dont think you can add custom headers while using `urllib`

but i know there are multiple ways to do it using [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

one way you could is like this:

import urllib2

```
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0' }
req = urllib2.Request('http://example.com/image.jpg', None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

with open('download.jpg','r+') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

this will download the image but the `'download.jpg'` has to already exist

there are more ways to do it i would take a look at this [Setting the User-Agent](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/user_agent.html)
 also take a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen)

Good Luck!