# Trouble downloading website using urllib(2) and requests - Bad status line

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to download pages from the site
http://statsheet.com/

like this

```
url = 'http://statsheet.com'
urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

I have tried with the Python modules urllib, urllib2 and "reqests", but I only get error messages like "got a bad status line", "BadStatusLine" or similar

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a common browser user agent e.g.

> wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.34
>   Safari/537.36" http://statsheet.com

Related question/answer:

[Changing user agent on urllib2.urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen)