# It is not possible to parse a part of a webpage that is visible when open with browser

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have this strange problem parsing the webpage [Herald Sun](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/help/rss) to get the list of rss from it. When I look at the webpage in the browser, I can see the links with titles. Though, when I used Python and Beautiful Soup to parse the page, the response does not even have the section I would like to parse.

```
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9) AppleWebKit/537.71 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Safari/537.71',
               'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
               'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
               'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req = urllib.request.Request("http://www.heraldsun.com.au/help/rss", headers=hdr)

try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.fp.read())

html_doc = page.read()

f = open("Temp/original.html", 'w')
f.write(html_doc.decode('utf-8'))
```

The written file as you can check, does not have the results in there, so obviously, Beautiful Soup has nothing to do here.

I wonder, how does the webpage enable this protection and how to overcome it? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For commercial use, read the terms of services First***

There are really not that much information the server know about who is making this request. 
Either IP, User-Agent or Cookie... Sometimes the urllib2 will not grab the information that are generated by JavaScript.

***JavaScript or Not?***

(1) You need to open up the chrome developer and disable the cache and Javascript to make sure that you can still see the information that you want. If you cannot see the information there, you have to use some tool that support Javascript like Selenium or PhantomJS. 
[image]

However, in this case, your website looks it is not that sophisticated.

***User-Agent? Cookie?***
(2) Then the problem ends up tuning User-Agent or Cookies. As you have tried before, the user agent seems like not enough. Then it will be the cookie that will play the trick.

[image]

As you can see, the first page call actually returns temporarily unavailable and you need to click the rss HTML　that with 200 return code. You just need to copy the user-agent and cookies from there and it will work.

[image]

Here are the codes how to add cookie using urllib2

```
import urllib2, bs4, re

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36")]
# I omitted the cookie here and you need to copy and paste your own
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'act-bg-i...eat_uuniq=1; criteo=; pl=true'))
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(opener.open("http://www.heraldsun.com.au/help/rss"))
div = soup.find('div', {"id":"content-2"}).find('div', {"class":"group-content"})

for a in div.find_all('a'):
    try:
        if 'feeds.news' in a['href']:
            print a 
    except:
        pass
```

And here are the outputs:

```
<a href="http://feeds.news.com.au/heraldsun/rss/heraldsun_news_breakingnews_2800.xml">Breaking News</a>
<a href="http://feeds.news.com.au/heraldsun/rss/heraldsun_news_topstories_2803.xml">Top Stories</a>
<a href="http://feeds.news.com.au/heraldsun/rss/heraldsun_news_worldnews_2793.xml">World News</a>
<a href="http://feeds.news.com.au/heraldsun/rss/heraldsun_news_morenews_2794.xml">Victoria and National News</a>
<a href="http://feeds.news.com.au/heraldsun/rss/heraldsun_news_sport_2789.xml">Sport News</a>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The site could very likely be serving different content, depending on the `User-Agent` string in the headers.  Websites will often do this for mobile browsers, for example.

Since you're not specifying one, [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#url-opener-objects) is going to use its default:

> By default, the URLopener class sends a User-Agent header of urllib/VVV, where VVV is the urllib version number.

You could try spoofing a common User-Agent string, by following the [advice in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen).  See [What's My User Agent?](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/)

Comment: in fact, I did use the User Agent, let me edit the question, as when I copy the code, I remove that part.

Comment: Sigh... and that's why it's a good reason to post your *actual* code.

Comment: I updated the code, it still has that error. I don't know if other elements have any effects.