# Can't install Minecraft Forge development environment

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have tried to install Minecraft Forge development environment [as described here](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Forge_Development_in_IntelliJ_IDEA), but I get this error:

```
================ Forge ModLoader Setup Start ===================
MCP Detected already, not downloading
Setting up MCP
Patching commands.py
patching file commands.py
    Commands patch applied successfully
Copying FML conf
Creating Repackaged data
    Creating re-packaged srg
    Creating re-packaged exc
    Creating re-packaged MCP patches
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 76, in <module>
    decompile=options.decompile, gen_conf=False)
  File "install.py", line 17, in fml_main
    disable_assets=disable_assets)
  File "/Users/jop/IdeaProjects/MinecraftPush Forge/forge/fml/fml.py", line 1013, in decompile_minecraft
    pre_decompile(mcp_dir, fml_dir, disable_assets=disable_assets)
  File "/Users/jop/IdeaProjects/MinecraftPush Forge/forge/fml/fml.py", line 1061, in pre_decompile
    download_minecraft(mcp_dir, fml_dir)
  File "/Users/jop/IdeaProjects/MinecraftPush Forge/forge/fml/fml.py", line 1125, in download_minecraft
    failed = download_libraries(mcp_dir, version_json['libraries'], mc_info['natives_dir']) or failed
  File "/Users/jop/IdeaProjects/MinecraftPush Forge/forge/fml/fml.py", line 1181, in download_libraries
    headers = get_headers(url)
  File "/Users/jop/IdeaProjects/MinecraftPush Forge/forge/fml/fml.py", line 173, in get_headers
    response = urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(url))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Minecraft Forge version are you trying to install?

Comment: @izstas I used the Recommended link in that wiki article

Answer (score 2):

It appears like you are unable to actually get the files. 
Returns in Error 403: Forbidden usaually means you don't have access to the that location.

**I reccomend first:**

Open the fml.py  (fml folder)

- search this:  `default_url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries'`
- and put it for:  `default_url = 'https://libraries.minecraft.net'`
- same with:  `base_url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Resources'`
- `base_url = 'http://resources.download.minecraft.net/'`

**If not then check:**

check your urlib, you may need to configure python to allow it to correctly download the files [Changing user agent on urllib2.urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen)

**This goes without saying:**

But obviously make sure you have updated all your programs and files to their latest version. *E.g. Forge, Minecraft, Java, Python ect.*

I hope this helps, if not let me know and I'd be happy to help.
Thanks,
Luke

Comment: The post you found this information on is outdated. This fix has already been integrated into fml.py. However I am also having this problem, both sites return a 403...

Comment: Right, so did you change the user agent on urllib2.urlopen? _'urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden'_ kinda suggests this. If you have then I know a few more things that can help.
Are you sure that everything is updated? I hate to ask, but it really is seeming like either your connection settings are wrong or forge is outdated.

Comment: After a bit more research, it looks like forge only supports the gradle version now. As for this error, you could be right that the user agent should be changed but I haven't tested it.

The tutorial Jop is using is outdated though.

Comment: @Lindenk okay great, I'm glad you got somewhere. I seriously recommend you rule out all possibilities before settling down with the version you have now if you are not happy with it. Anyway, I am just glad you got a result out of it. If you do have questions about the urlib then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Another reason for this error could be as follows:**

In my experience, launching the gradlew batch file has led to denial of download when running connection-tampering software/hardware such as a **VPN** (*Virtual Private Network*).

If you are using a VPN, consider disabling it whilst launching gradle and setting up your workspace.