# Error 1010 (banned access)

Tags: browser, cloudflare

I hope this isn't too off topic, but despite being an avid reader of stackoverlow I don't have enough reputation to post this to meta so I've had to post to the main forum.

I access this site almost every day and have found it to be a great resource. However, today I began to experience some severe problems. When attempting to access the site with my usual browser (vimprobable2) I recieved Error 1010 with the messege:

> The owner of this website (stackoverflow.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature.

I found that I could still access the site with firefox, but that the connection was reset every few seconds (it has taken far to long to even get to the question asking page...).

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913699/the-owner-of-this-website-has-banned-your-access-based-on-your-browsers-signat) suggesting that the Error 1010 problem was caused by a user agent. I modified my vimprobablerc file to output the same user agent as my firefox browser: *"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0"* But, even with this change, I still get Error 1010. The CloudFlare site suggests that this can only be resolve by admins at stackoverflow or by using another browser. Given the resets being caused through firefox, the later option doesn't seem feasible. Even if it were, my setup is mouseless so my browser options are a bit limited.

My question is 3-fold.

1. If it is not the useragent causing this error, then what is?
2. Is there anything I can do from my end to resolve this other than "use another browser"?
3. Is there a place (other than the meta forum) to report such errors to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3):

You should actually send this to CloudFlare support & we can take a look. It might be some browser plugin or extension throwing something off as well.