# Python urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable on valid website

Tags: python, urllib2

I have been using Amazon's Product Advertising API to generate urls that contains prices for a given book. One url that I have generated is the following:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0415376327%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJZY2VTI5JQ66K7QQ%26tag%3Damaztest04-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0415376327

When I click on the link or paste the link on the address bar, the web page loads fine. However, when I execute the following code I get an error:

```
url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0415376327%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJZY2VTI5JQ66K7QQ%26tag%3Damaztest04-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0415376327"
html_contents = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

The error is **urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable**. First of all, I don't understand why I even get this error since the web page successfully loads.

Also, another weird behavior that I have noticed is that the following code sometimes does and sometimes does not give the stated error:

```
html_contents = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0415376327%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJZY2VTI5JQ66K7QQ%26tag%3Damaztest04-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0415376327")
```

I am totally lost on how this behavior occurs. Is there any fix or work around to this? My goal is to read the html contents of the url.

**EDIT**

I don't know why stack overflow is changing my code to change the amazon link I listed above in my code to rads.stackoverflow. Anyway, ignore the rads.stackoverflow link and use my link above between the quotes.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `rads.stackoverflow.com` is (or was) an advertising service the SO implemented and then scrapped. It may very well be that there is some sort of use limitation (referrer, client and what not)

Comment: For some random reason, I don't know why the link changes to contain the stack overflow tag. However, if I keep the copy and paste link on the address bar, the website works fine.

Comment: Ah I see! Nice :) This must be SO comment parser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because Amazon don't allow automated access to their data, so they're rejecting your request because it didn't come from a proper browser. If you look at the content of the 503 response, it says:

> To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact
>   api-services-support@amazon.com.
>       For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_5_sv,
>   or our Product Advertising API at
>   https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_5_ac
>   for advertising use cases.

This is because the `User-Agent` for Python's `urllib` is so obviously not a browser. You could always fake the `User-Agent`, but that's not really good (or moral) practice.

As a side note, as mentioned in another answer, the `requests` library is really good for HTTP access in Python.

Comment: I was looking into your statement about using a User-Agent and was wondering if I needed to do something along the lines of adding headers like this for urllib2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen

Comment: Yes, that's how you change the User-Agent. Again, the `requests` library [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is much better for this.

Comment: There is nothing immoral about faking the user agent (or any other private data)!!! These companies (or anyone) don't have a god-given right to know what browser you use, or what device you own or what websites you visit. The more people lie about their data, the better. They can and will use that information against you. They don't hesitate a second to gain advantage over you, so shouldn't you!

Answer (score 28):

Amazon is rejecting the default User-Agent for urllib2 . One workaround is to use the requests module

```
import requests
page = requests.get("http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0415376327%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJZY2VTI5JQ66K7QQ%26tag%3Damaztest04-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0415376327")
html_contents = page.text
```

If you insist on using urllib2, this is how a header can be faked to do it:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open('http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/0415376327%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJZY2VTI5JQ66K7QQ%26tag%3Damaztest04-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D386001%26creativeASIN%3D0415376327')
html_contents = response.read()
```

Don't worry about stackoverflow editing the URL. They explain that they are doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls).

Comment: For some weird reason, the link changes to contain the stack overflow tag. However, if you copy and paste the link on the address bar, everything works fine. Can you update your answer using my following link to see if it works because it doesn't work for me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is compressing longer links or probably any external link to display content in a cleaner fashion. This might also be out of security vulnerabilities of pasting actual links into what can be formatted as code on the interface. In your real code, put whatever link you like and everything should work fine.

Comment: python 3 version?

Answer (score 0):

Ben's answer is the correct and the accepted answer to the OP's question (I guess; I haven't validated it).

However, since this question is the first hit when googling for 'python 503 urllib2', and it does not solve the problem I spent the last three hours investigating...  I'll offer an alternate answer.

If you're unlucky enough to be dealing with Python 2.6 (in 2023!), you're probably *really* out of luck.

TLS' SNI was first introduced in Python 3 and backported to Python 2.7 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27717544/8280541), but never added to 2.6 or prior.  Nowadays, many if not most HTTPS servers will depend on SNI.

Long story short, SNI allows a single HTTPS server to serve several different sites, with potentially different certificates.  When a client connects to the server via HTTPS, one of the first things it does is to provide the server its SNI (Server Name Indication), even before they talk certs.  With that information, the server will be able to provide to the client the content of the site they want, and the associated certificate.

To confirm you're in this situation:

- Are you running Python 2.6 or previous?
- Confirm  you can access the same address from the same host, using a different Python version, `curl` or some other tool
- Run `openssl s_client -connect my.server.url:443 < /dev/null | grep subject`; take note of the server name it shows (it should be the one you're expecting)
- Run `openssl s_client -noservername -connect my.server.url:443 < /dev/null | grep subject`; the server name changed

If that's the case, Python 2.6 is not for you.  Time to upgrade, perhaps?  If you still insist in using ancient and unsupported software, one alternative is to run `curl` through `subprocess.Popen` to get what you want.