# Inability to extract data from website using urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was following a tutorial on pythonforbeginners.com, and I came across a code which isn't running right on my OSX.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://www.pythonforbeginners.com"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print soup.prettify()
```

This gives me the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/dhruvmullick/CS/Python/Extracting Data/test.py", line 8, in
>   
>       content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 127, in urlopen
>       return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 410, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 523, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 448, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 382, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 531, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [403 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) indicates that the server is blocking your connection.

> ...a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action.

Try with a different domain and you'll find that it works as expected.

To make a work-around, you can add a [custom user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802146/2327328).

Comment: Is there a reason why this domain is blocking my connection, whereas others are not?

Comment: The server could be blocking any request without a user agent. See the link at the bottom for steps to add a user agent.