# Problems crawling wordreference

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, lxml

I am trying to crawl `wordreference`, but I am not succeding.

The first problem I have encountered is, that a big part is loaded via `JavaScript`, but that shouldn't be much problem because I can see what I need in the source code.

So, for example, I want to extract for a given word, the first two meanings, so in this url: `http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=crane` I need to extract `grulla` and `grúa`.

This is my code:

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=crane'
doc = lh.parse((urllib2.urlopen(url)))
trans = doc.xpath('//td[@class="ToWrd"]/text()')

for i in trans:

    print i
```

The result is that I get an empty list.

I have tried to crawl it with scrapy too, no success. I am not sure what is going on, the only way I have been able to crawl it is using `curl`, but that is sloopy, I want to do it in an elegant way, with Python.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a `User-Agent` header to be sent, see [Changing user agent on urllib2.urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen).

Also, just switching to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) would do the trick (it automatically sends the `python-requests/version` User Agent by default):

```
import lxml.html as lh
import requests

url = 'http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=crane'

response = requests.get("http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=crane")
doc = lh.fromstring(response.content)

trans = doc.xpath('//td[@class="ToWrd"]/text()')
for i in trans:
    print(i)
```

Prints:

```
grulla 
grúa 
plataforma 
...
grulla blanca 
grulla trompetera
```

Comment: Thank you but, what is the reason it doesn't work with the `User Agent`  `urllib`. I have crawled other websites that one without problems, why not this one¿?