# Weird json value urllib python

Tags: python, json, urllib

I'm trying to manipulate a dynamic JSON from this site:

```
http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/imagemCaptcha.do
```

It has 3 elements, `imagem`, a base64, `labelValorCaptcha`, just a message, and `uuidCaptcha`, a value to pass by parameter to play a sound in this link bellow:

```
http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/somCaptcha.do?timestamp=1455996420264&uuidCaptcha=sajcaptcha_e7b072e1fce5493cbdc46c9e4738ab8a
```

When I enter in the first site through a browser and put in the second link the uuidCaptha after the equal ("..uuidCaptcha="), the sound plays normally. I wrote a simple code to catch this elements.

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/imagemCaptcha.do"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
urlSound = "http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/somCaptcha.do?timestamp=1455996420264&uuidCaptcha="
print urlSound + data['uuidCaptcha']
```

But I dont know what's happening, the caught value of the `uuidCaptcha` doesn't work. Open a error web page.

Someone knows?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the error? What does the print statement output?

Comment: Also you probably need to insert the current timestamp: `import time` at the start, then change the definition of urlSound to

`urlSound = "http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/somCaptcha.do?timestamp=" + str(int(time.time())) + "&uuidCaptcha="`

The str(int(…)) rounds the timestamp to the nearest second, and then converts it to a string so that it can be used in the URL

Comment: @CharlieHarding The print output should be a link that open a sound, like [this](http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/somCaptcha.do?timestamp=1455996420264&uuidCaptcha=sajcaptcha_407e9a85a31d49588c429cdd4c41bd1d).

Comment: @CharlieHarding The timestamp is just to prevent cache, doesn't stop the sound be opened. You can put any valid timestamp there.

Comment: You say that it should output this string, but it doesn't. What does it output: can you paste the error here? It could be that you are simply running Python 3, in which case the print statement should be a function: `print(urlSound + data['uuidCaptcha'])`

Comment: @CharlieHarding Theres no error message to paste, just a wrong link formed by urlSound + data['uuidCaptcha']. As I wrote at the end of the question, the output link should play a sound.

Comment: Could it be because of the user agent of the python fetching script?

Comment: @CharlieHarding great! The best way is download the page ang get the values, because this JSON is dynamic and need an opened link to exist (sorry for a late answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said @Charlie Harding, the best way is download the page and get the JSON values, because this JSON is dynamic and need an opened web link to exist.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
$ cat a.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import urllib, json


url = "http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/imagemCaptcha.do"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
urlSound = "http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/somCaptcha.do?timestamp=1455996420264&uuidCaptcha="
print urlSound + data['uuidCaptcha']

$ python a.py
http://esaj.tjsc.jus.br/cposgtj/somCaptcha.do?timestamp=1455996420264&uuidCaptcha=sajcaptcha_efc8d4bc3bdb428eab8370c4e04ab42c
```

Comment: Should open an audio.