# Website opens in the browser but return 403 when opened in Python

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-403, urlopen

There is a website which happily opens in a browser and returns a 403 HTTP error when opened in Python as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

link = 'http://niezalezna.pl/'

r = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

print soup.prettify()
```

The website is a popular news service. Is it then possible to make a URL return HTTP 403 error when opened using a piece of code like above? 
Thanks,

Comment: This means that the site doesn't allow scrapers. fake a user agent to get past this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Look up how to set a user-agent with urllib2

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer thanks to the comments above. The code is below and the full answer can be found here: [Changing user agent on urllib2.urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802134/changing-user-agent-on-urllib2-urlopen)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

link = 'http://niezalezna.pl/'

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

print soup.prettify()
```